# MacBook Pro suddenly not connecting to HDMI

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I have a MacBook Pro and regularly connect it to a Samsung TV via HDMI.

Suddenly, it has stopped working - when I connect the cable the screen looks like it is about to share, then comes back.
To my knowledge, I did not run a software update.

I have tried 2 different cables (one with, one without USB-C multi adaptor [not apple], both which worked in the past
(and the multi adaptor is recognised when external hardrives plugged in instead) . Tried both thunderbolt ports.

This is clearly a Mac issue. I tried resetting the NVRAM - all that happens is the screen intermittently turns on and off whilst I hold down the keys (is this correct?)

Anyone know how I could fix this issue?? 
Many thanks!

Comment: You say it’s “clearly a Mac issue”.  Did you confirm that the input to the Samsung TV is still working and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

In System Preferences > Displays > Arrangement > turn Mirroring on or off, whichever it wasn't set at.

Then resetting the NVRAM again https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

and the last opportunity is to change the Mirroring back to what is was before and reset after that the NVRAM again.

I hope I could help you..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately that did not work. I notice that if I click  "detect displays" it briefly swaps to the apple loading screen. Also when loading, at this precise point the screen flickers.

Comment: seems strange to me ... have you already tried a other device than the samsung tv?

Comment: I haven't got one unfortunately, but I did swap HDMI ports on the TV. I still think it is a Mac Display issue however, as when I am repeatedly trying to display share, I lost some content on the  browser page I had open. (i.e. I was on Whattsap web and some contact disappeared unless I opened the same chat again)

Comment: Also this could be most important: I can get it to work, but it seems to depend on a "stable" (physically) connection.... so if I move the computer it drops....then sometimes reconnects..... but most often doesn't.  But this is strange as I have tried two different cables, and both thunderbolt ports - so what I am seeing is similar to a cable issue, yet can't be.

Comment: very special. So you can rule out that it is due to the hdmi cable, the thunderbold connection or the samsung screen ... hmmm

Comment: ok actually this is even more incredible, it connects then I move the cable 1 millimetre, loses it, reconnects, 1 millimetres, loses it reconnects,  .....10millimeter, loses it entirely

Maybe I have two broken cables?? this is crazy

Comment: no that can hardly be... and the adapter thunderbold-hdmi works realy?

Comment: its not specifically thunderbolt adaptor just. USB3, but my laptop  sees the USB connections to it fine (external hard rive etc) 

but I am replicating exactly the issue with a straight USB3-HDMI cable.  (both of these cables have worked just fine  in the past to the same purpose!)

Comment: really special ... I don't know anything else.. sorry